# Different name for a generated XSD attribute from that of the java object

Tags: jaxb

Is it possible to generate a XSD from Java object with a name different that of the class or its attribute ? Say I have a class having an attribute "currency" and in the generated xsd i want to rename it as "currencyType"?

Answer (score 0):

Many of the JAXB (JSR-222) annotations (i.e. `@XmlElement`, `@XmlAttribute`, `@XmlType`, etc) enable you to specify a name to override the default one derived from the class or property name.

```java
@XmlElement(name="currencyType")
public String getCurrency() {
    return currency;
}
```